# Awk failing extraction

Tags: awk

I have a huge file containing the xyz positions of some atoms from different molecules. The whole file contains ~ 10000 configurations. I have created a script that iterates over the total number of configurations and extracts the coordinates associated with a specific atomic species that is systematically repeated at a fixed position, along with each frame associated with each system. My code works perfectly, except in the case in which the atomic position coincides with the last position of the frame I have to process, skipping to grab it and print in the corresponding file.

Each frame contains 384 atoms. In the xyz format, we have to take into account two extra lines at the beginning, where the number of atoms (in this case 384, line #1) and a blank/commented line are (line #2) are located. 
The awk file with the list of atoms position lines is of the form:

```
        {n = NR%386}
    n == 1 {print "24"; next}
    n == 2 ||
    n == 91 ||
    ...
    n == 378 ||
    n == 380 ||
    n == 381 ||
    n == 386
```

where the `n=NR%386` is the number of lines that awk has to account at every iteration in order to have the correct number of frames, in

```
    n == 1 {print "24"; next}
```

the code prints the number of atoms I want to extract for each frame, in this case, 24.

The problem arises with the last value, in the last position of each frame before advancing to the next frame:

```
   n == 386
```

When using the command

```
awk -f file.awk filename.xyz >> test.txt
```

the code will skip reading, extracting, and printing the last coordinate.

The filename.xyz I have to process is something like:

```
384
 i =     3171, time =     3171.000, E =     -3298.3005315786
C      6.66359796   19.29831718   16.63773520
C      6.19922671   19.83243350   15.35406226
C      7.73577004   21.24303011   16.94974860
C      7.32315891   21.77975003   15.67093925
N      5.08248005   17.55384984   15.51887635
N      7.75857672   23.00895664   15.43811018
N      8.58649028   22.07495287   17.61330368
N      7.45555304   19.97249138   17.42360101
...
...
...
N      3.62924684   23.22942656   15.38486984
N      4.52670891   22.25077226   17.55981432
N      3.17369677   20.23465407   17.45881199
N      2.28230853   21.30557433   14.86646780
S      1.48394488   18.18032187   17.21253664
S      0.70072709   19.13053602   14.60582837
S      4.67511560   23.53830074   16.57005901
```

Currently, just trying to extract only position 386

```
n == 386
```

produces something like:

```
1
 i =     3171, time =     3171.000, E =     -3298.3005315786
1
 i =     3172, time =     3172.000, E =     -3298.3023115390
1
 i =     3173, time =     3173.000, E =     -3298.3056102462
1
 i =     3174, time =     3174.000, E =     -3298.3101590395
```

that are just the corresponding to the commented lines, apparently skipping or not correctly interpreting which line to grep.

I would like to understand why awk if not able to extract the last line properly and how to solve the problem.

Comment: Where is this `1` coming from in your `produces something like` output. Also I'm confused about your modulus calculation. If you are wanting the last line in a frame (the 386'th) then you would be after `n==0{print $0}`... but that doesn't really foot with how your `n==1` is behaving.... it's like your sample data doesn't line up with your `produces something like:` based on the awk script you've shown.

Comment: I think @eewanco has the right answer. In the future, realize we don't need to see 386 lines of input (or even a hint at it). Reduce your problem to code that people can copy/paste into their environment and easily test with. Glad you have a solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a math problem. `NR%386` will never be 386 because of the way the modulus operator works (there is no remainder when you divide 386 by 386). So your `n==386` will never get executed. Try using `(NR-1)%386` instead of `NR%386` and shift all your conditionals accordingly:

```
n == 0 {print "24"; next}
```

etc. If you need `n` for calculations, add one to it.